# PayPal cancel a recurring payment subscription using java sdk

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

In our application an organization subscribe to a particular plan on the basis of number of users into the organization. Now if organization tries to update its plan then I need to cancel its previous plan. How this can be done?
At this moment I am thinking to let the organization to subscribe to the new plan and cancel his previous plan as soon as I got success notification on to MY IPN handler.

But I have no idea about how to cancel previous subscription. Its a recurring payment subscription on yearly basis. I also have a doubt if I cancel a subscription will the remaining amount get refunded to the customer ?